# Remove bind eventListener from Gia component

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

I'm very new to modules and components and working with frameworks. I'm trying to work with [Gia](https://github.com/giantcz/gia) to get started.

I've set up an `eventListener` which gets added to a button within Gia's `mount()` method and it binds the component in order to have access to the component's element (change classes, style, etc.).

How do I remove the `eventListener` in the `unmount()` method? I know the issue is due to the new function-reference created by the `bind()` method. I just don't know how to access and remove it.

```
class navigation extends Component {
  //
  // Construct
  constructor(element) {
    super(element);
    //
    this.ref = {
      navButton: null,
      navLinks: [],
    };
  }
  //
  // Mount
  mount() {
    //
    // Listen for click
    var listener = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.ref.navButton.addEventListener("click", listener);
    //

  }
  //
  // Unmount
  unmount() {
    //
    // Stop listening for click
    this.ref.navButton.removeEventListener("click", listener);
  }
  //
  // Click-handlers
  handleClick() {
    this.element.classList.toggle("closed");
  }
}
//
// Export component
export default navigation;
```

(Similar answers provide solutions for React scenarios, I was not able to adapt them for my case, hence this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining the `listener` variable inside `mount`, define a variable in the constructor and use the same for adding or removing the listener

```js
class navigation extends Component {
  //
  // Construct
  constructor(element) {
    super(element);
    //
    this.ref = {
      navButton: null,
      navLinks: [],
    };
    this.listener = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  // Mount
  mount() {
    this.ref.navButton.addEventListener("click", this.listener);
  }

  // Unmount
  unmount() {

    // Stop listening for click
    this.ref.navButton.removeEventListener("click", this.listener);
  }

  // Click-handlers
  handleClick() {
    this.element.classList.toggle("closed");
  }
}
//
// Export component
export default navigation;
```

Hope this solves the issue that you are facing.

The same example using arrow functions instead of using `bind`

```js
class navigation extends Component {
  //
  // Construct
  constructor(element) {
    super(element);
    //
    this.ref = {
      navButton: null,
      navLinks: [],
    };
  }

  // Mount
  mount() {
    this.ref.navButton.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  }

  // Unmount
  unmount() {

    // Stop listening for click
    this.ref.navButton.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
  }

  // Click-handlers
  handleClick = () => {
    this.element.classList.toggle("closed");
  }
}
//
// Export component
export default navigation;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware I can define it in the constructor. This is great knowledge to build on and solves my current problem.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped in solving your problem. And if you use arrow functions you can get rid of `this.listener = this.handleClick.bind(this);` and directly use `handleClick` for adding and removing event listener.

Comment: Can you write an example? Most modern Javascript syntax is new to me, I'm still learning the concepts.

Comment: Sure, Please check the answer, I have Updated with arrow function as well.